# NodeJS returning Map and React accessing it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, dictionary

I need a map to replace some content in my React application. I have a NodeJS where I return a map.

```
let output = new Map();
output.set("#propertyName#", property.PropertyName || "");
output.set("#propertyPhone#", property.PropertyPhone || "");
output.set("#propertyEmail#", property.PropertyEmail || "");
output.set("#propertyStreet#", property.PropertyAddress1 || "");
// ... I have a lot more of output.set. The property variable is a database query response
// Then, I return it as an array. I tried to return the map object and it returned an empty object {}
res.json([...output]);
```

The problem is that it returns an array instead of my map.

```
[
    [
        "#propertyName#",
        "ABC"
    ],
    [
        "#propertyPhone#",
        "123"
    ],
    [
        "#propertyEmail#",
        "None@none.com"
    ],
    [
        "#propertyStreet#",
        "123 main"
    ]
]
```

Is there a way to convert this array back to a Map in React? Or even better, could I return a Map from NodeJS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending data from the Node server to the react app uses JSON, there is no Map in JSON. Fortunately you can pass in the array when making a map.

`const myMap = new Map(serverData)`